# Why is it not allowed to use variable-length arrays as vector element?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   vector<int[]> vec;//serious compiler error
   vector<int[2]> vec={{1,2}};//error:array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
}
```

In addition, how to rectify the grammar of the second one? I already use a brace-enclosed initializer.

Comment: The type you pass into a `vector` must be fixed at compile time. In an array, the size is part of the type. If you want something that is conceptually a "variable-length array", that is exactly what `vector` is for!

Comment: `vector<array<int,2>>` for the second one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a variable-length array, those do not exist in C++. It's an array without a size specifier, an incomplete type that doesn't meet the requirements of most (all?) vector operations.

The second attempt tries to copy c-arrays (list initialization always does copying), and that too is not supported.

If you want a vector of arrays, spell it as `std::vector<std::array<int, 2>>`.

Comment: but `vector<int[2]> vec;` could be compiled without error. So `vector<int[2]> vec;` is OK but not support list initialization?

Comment: @bigxiao - Yes, because the default constructor of vector isn't instantiated with an operation that is illegal for c-arrays. Each vector c'tor is going to be different in that regard. You can't treat c-arrays as value types, they just aren't. That's what `std::array` exists for now.

Comment: @bigxiao That's because in template classes, only the functions that are used are compiled further than basic syntax checks. And `std::vector<>`'s default constructor doesn't use anything `int[2]` doesn't provide. The same is not true for the constructor you are using.

Comment: @Frank cppref says vector's  element must be copy assignable. But c-array are not copy assignable. Why could it be compiled?

Comment: @StoryTeller strange thing. `vector<int[2]> vec;` could be compiled, but if I use `vec.resize(1)`, it could not be compiled.

Comment: @bigxiao You should read the next paragraph that says this depends on which operations are used on the vector.

Comment: @bigxiao - Not really that odd. `resize` is another member whose requirements a c-array does not meet.

Comment: @StoryTeller Then how to add element into such vector?

Comment: @bigxiao - You can't. It's just not supported. That's not to say a vector of fixed sized arrays is not useful, but you need to use `std::array` for that, to make it a value type.